# JavaScript behavior change depending on how page is loaded

Tags: javascript, html, browser

I am having an issue where seemingly the way JavaScript executes is changing depending on whether I open a file from a brand new browser tab (copy-pasting the link in) versus if I open the page by clicking a link from another page.

A summarized version of my code is:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      try {
        // ...other code...
        throw new Error("error");        

      } catch (e) {
        location.href =
          "https:\/\/google.com"; // would be "https:\/\/mysite.com"
      }
      window.close();
    </script>
  </head>
</html>
```

If I open this in a brand new tab by copy-pasting the link, the tab will navigate to https://google.com

However, if I open the link via a hyperlink, the new tab closes immediately.

Ideally, I want the redirect to be successful regardless of how the page is loaded.

Would love to understand what's going on here as the above code snippet is from an external library that I can't modify

Appreciate any insight or help!

Answer (score 0):

[From MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/close):

> This method can only be called on windows that were opened by a script using the `Window.open()` method, or on top-level windows that have a single history entry. If the window doesn't match these requirements, an error similar to this one appears in the console: `Scripts may not close windows that were not opened by script.`

In other words, a page opened by clicking a link on another site cannot use `window.close()`. However, if you create it with `window.open()`, that restriction does not apply and you can use `window.close()`, which is overriding your redirect. Ctrl clicking on a link to open it in a new tab also satisfies this condition. You can verify that by running `window.close()` in the devtools console and seeing whether or not it closes the tab.

Comment: *"if you open the page directly"* the text you quoted doesn't say that at all, it says only the pages opened through `window.open()` can be closed this way.

Comment: @asportnoy That explanation makes sense for the most part but I'm having a hard time reconciling that with this behavior:

On website A, user clicks `<a href>` link with no target, new page loads, `window.close()` is blocked (tested using your devtools trick).

On website B, user clicks `<a href with target="_blank>` to open the same link in a new tab, new page loads, `window.close()` closes the tab.

Is there some relationship between `window.open()` and specifying a target in an `<a>` tag?

Ideally I want a new tab to open and `window.close()` to be restricted if possible.

Comment: For what it's worth, I fixed the MDN article, you might want to update your quote.

Comment: If your only goal is to disable `window.close()` you can override the method on the window object: `window.close = undefined` or `window.close = () => {}`.

This is not necessarily recommended, but if you want to override the behaviour you can do it.